# DynamicList returns list of entities with null values

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, brokerquery

Originally, I had extended `DynamicList<FAQs, SimpleBrokerQuery>` from my custom model FAQsContentList where I want to execute a SimpleBrokerQuery on a few filterKeywords. In the logs I can see that I get query results but when it goes through the default Model Builder, the entity returns n results with null values. Originally I get a list of entity objects but with null values `c.s.d.t.m.impl.DefaultModelBuilder - Expected class is pre-set to class com.sdl.dxa.modules.faqs.model.FAQs for model EntityModelData(id=4979, componentTemplate=null, linkUrl=null, content=null, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)`

Now, I get the another error (shown below) when I played around with the template, but the bottom issue is that I am not getting any field values.

The exception is `.api.mapping.semantic.SemanticMappingException: Ambiguous semantic mapping for http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:FAQs, found these mappings: [class com.sdl.dxa.modules.faqs.model.FAQs, class com.sdl.dxa.modules.faqs.model.FAQs]` but there are no core schemas called FAQs

```
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Exception happened while creating a entity model from: EntityModelData(id=4560, componentTemplate=null, linkUrl=null, content=null, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)     at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:133)  at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:86)    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider._convertEntities(DefaultContentProvider.java:120)    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider.populateDynamicList(DefaultContentProvider.java:213)     ... 122 common frames omitted Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Cannot get a view model tpe because of semantic mapping exception   at 

com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:109)


Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.mapping.semantic.SemanticMappingException: Ambiguous semantic mapping for http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:FAQs, found these mappings: [class com.sdl.dxa.modules.faqs.model.FAQs, class com.sdl.dxa.modules.faqs.model.FAQs]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMappingRegistryImpl.getEntityClassByFullyQualifiedName(SemanticMappingRegistryImpl.java:334)
```

To resolve the SemanticMappingException caused by Ambiguous semantic mapping, I then created a customTeaser which is mapped to my schema FAQs `@SemanticEntity(entityName = "FAQs", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "f")`
. In my custom ContentListController.enrichModel function, when it calls `contentProvider.populateDynamicList(dynamicList, webRequestContext.getLocalization());`, I can see from the logs that it calls my custom DynamicList and the DefaultModelBuilder that is called after this prints the following logs.

```
c.s.d.t.m.impl.DefaultModelBuilder - Expected class is pre-set to class com.sdl.dxa.modules.contentlist.model.ContentTeaser for model EntityModelData(id=4560, componentTemplate=null, linkUrl=null, content=null, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)
09:33:37.128 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationCacheOperationSource - Adding cacheable method 'getMappedModelTypes' with attribute: [Builder[public java.lang.Class com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(java.util.Set,java.lang.Class) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException] caches=[defaultCache] | key='' | keyGenerator='localizationAwareKeyGenerator' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false']
09:33:37.128 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'localizationAwareKeyGenerator'
09:33:37.128 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'cacheManager'
09:33:37.138 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'genericSemanticModelDataConverter'
09:33:37.138 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'r2modelBuilder'
09:33:37.139 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.i.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=question, tail=null) for semantic field
09:33:37.145 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.i.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=answer, tail=null) for semantic field
09:33:37.152 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.i.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=faqsByTopic, tail=null) for semantic field
09:33:37.155 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.i.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=active, tail=null) for semantic field
```

Comment: To bypass the SemanticMappingException, I created a customTeaser to map all FAQs schema fields. Now I don't get the SemanticException, but I get the following: .DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=question, tail=null) for semantic field

Comment: That error about "ambiguous semantic mapping" looks really fishy: it is reporting the same class 2 times. So, it seems there is not really an ambiguous mapping; this seems to be a bug in DXA. Makes sense to report this on GitHub: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues

Comment: @RickPannekoek thanks for the reply. Could you suggest some workaround until the bug is fixed? Note that we are already working on a workaround as explained in https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18689/how-to-get-value-of-a-list-of-list-of-richtext-or-richtextdata