# How to get value of a list of list of RichText or RichTextData

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

One of the `ContentModelData` returns content in the below format.

### Code 1

```
content =  {question=Question 1?, answer={paraContent=RichTextData(fragments=[No. Answer 1 <strong>Strong text here</strong> Answer continues <br /> Answer para 2.])}}
```

question has value of type `String`, and answer is a list of paragraphs containing `heading`, list of `paraContent`. List of `paracontent` is actually a list of `RichText`. Now sometimes `paraContent` is simply a list of `RichText` fields but when we create RichText Data, `RichTextData` fragments are created. I have tried many methods.

### Code 2

```
1. paraMultiLevel= (List<ParagraphMultiLevel>)
    content.getAndCast("answer", ParagraphMultiLevel.class);

2. paraMultiLevel2 = (List<ParagraphMultiLevel>)content.getElement("answer");

3. (List<ParagraphMultiLevel>)content.get("answer")
```

None of the above populates my entity `viewModel`. I am getting an exception

> com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.ContentModelData cannot be cast to
>   java.util.List

How can I fetch the `Answer` value and set it on a List `<List<ParagraphMultiLevel>` so I can access it in my view?

## Update on 04/04/2018

When I originally tried to `convertEntites(List<ComponentMetadata>)` (see code 3), it returned `null` values so then I had to manually iterate over the list of ids and got the `EntityModelData` using `DefaultModelService.loadEntity()`.
From the `EntityModelData` I get the `ContentModelData` (see Code 1). I want to set my `customTeaser.content` with `ContentModelData.get("answer")`.

### Code 3

```
try { dynamicList.setQueryResults(customContentProvider._convertEntities(components, dynamicList.getEntityType(), localization), query.isHasMore());
} catch (DxaException e) {
    throw new ContentProviderException("Cannot populate a dynamic list " + dynamicList.getId() + " localization " + localization.getId(), e);
}
```

returned `[ContentTeaser(headline=null, introduction=null, content=null,...`

### Code 4

```
 @SemanticEntities({
     @SemanticEntity(entityName = "FAQs", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "f")
 })

 public class ContentTeaser extends AbstractEntityModel {
     @JsonProperty("Headline")
     private String headline;

     @SemanticProperty("f:question")
     @JsonProperty("Introduction")
     private String introduction;

     @SemanticProperty("f:answer")
     @JsonProperty("Content")
     private List<ParagraphMultiLevel> content;             
 }
```

### Code 5

```
@SemanticEntity(entityName = "ParagraphMultiLevel", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "pml")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class ParagraphMultiLevel extends AbstractEntityModel {      
    @SemanticProperty("pml:heading")
    @JsonProperty("Heading")
    private String heading;

    @SemanticProperty("pml:paraContent")
    @JsonProperty("ParaContent")
    private List<RichText> paraContent;

    @SemanticProperty("pml:subParagraph")
    @JsonProperty("SubParagraph")
    private List<SubParagraphLevel2> subParagraph;

    @SemanticProperty("pml:paraFootnote")
    @JsonProperty("ParaFootnote")
    private List<RichText> paraFootnote;
}
```

Comment: How did you define your View Model classes? And where are you trying to use this mapping logic? Direct access to the R2 Data Model (e.g. `ContentModelData`) is only expected in Model Builders, which is considered an advanced extension point which is normally not needed.

Comment: Thanks @RickPannekoek for responding. I have updated my question to explain why I needed to access the R2 Data Model.

Comment: @RickPannekoek please also take a look at another post which explains why we had to opt for this approach (directly accessing R2 data model). We were unable to populate entities/models using the standard DynamicList functionality.

https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/dynamiclist-returns-list-of-entities-with-null-values

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to mix the R2 Data Model (e.g. `ContentModelData`) with your Strongly Typed View Models (e.g. `ParagraphMultiLevel`). That doesn’t work.

The DXA Semantic Mapping logic is used to map the data in the R2 Data Model to Strongly Typed View Models, but these are distinct models; you won’t be able to simply cast one to the other.

See, for example: 
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/master/dxa-framework/dxa-tridion-provider/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/tridion/mapping/EntityModelBuilder.java