# Component Link field returns null: Cannot convert a entity model to class for a semantic field

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

Below is the logs I am getting for a component link field. It is a simple single text field schema (CodeBlock). The component link field returns null. There is no error in schema mapping.

```
15:47:52.136 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.impl.DefaultModelBuilder - Expected class is pre-set to class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.CodeBlock for model EntityModelData(id=13327, componentTemplate=ComponentTemplateData(id=169, title=null, revisionDate=0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, outputFormat=null, metadata=null), linkUrl=, content={code=Your request has been received and a customer service representative will contact you shortly.}, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)

15:47:52.150 [ajp-nio-8214-exec-1] ERROR c.s.w.c.i.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl - Exception while getting field data for: private com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.CodeBlock com.sdl.dxa.modules.onlineforms.model.OnlineForm.webMessage
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.exceptions.FieldConverterException: Cannot convert a entity model 13327 to class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.CodeBlock for semantic field webMessage
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:43)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:17)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:65)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:135)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl$1.doWith(SemanticMapperImpl.java:126)

Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Exception happened while creating a entity model from: EntityModelData(id=13327, componentTemplate=ComponentTemplateData(id=169, title=null, revisionDate=0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, outputFormat=null, metadata=null), linkUrl=, content={code=Your request has been received and a customer service representative will contact you shortly.}, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:86)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:37)
    ... 84 common frames omitted

Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Cannot get a view model tpe because of semantic mapping exception
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:109)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)

Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.mapping.semantic.SemanticMappingException: Ambiguous semantic mapping for http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:CodeBlock, found these mappings: [class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.CodeBlock, class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.CodeBlock]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMappingRegistryImpl.getEntityClassByFullyQualifiedName(SemanticMappingRegistryImpl.java:334)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:107)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like a similar spurious error as reported here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/dynamiclist-returns-list-of-entities-with-null-values

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the model is added to your webapp twice? In the last error in the stacktrace, we can see this

```
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.mapping.semantic.SemanticMappingException: Ambiguous semantic mapping for http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:CodeBlock, found these mappings: [class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.CodeBlock, class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.CodeBlock]
```